# Quagga, Zebra routing manager daemon does not start

Tags: networking, systemd, services

When I run `zebra.service start` I get an error saying the unit file changed and it does not start:

[image: errors attempting to start the service]

[image: unit file contents]

Comment: The command suggested should be literally run. Did you try running `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`?

Comment: yea i tried and same issue